# IntelliJ Select an interpreter to see the installed packages

Tags: python, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ 2021.2.1. My workspace has some Java projects (JDK11).

I then created a Flask project in pycharm and imported it to my workspace. I can run it, but when I view the "Python Packages" tab in IntelliJ, it says "Select an interpreter to see the installed packages".

In Project Structure | SDKs, I have JDK 11 as well as my Conda environment.

How do I get Python Packages to work in IntelliJ with a Java workspace?

Also, Tools | Manage Python Packages IS working, just the tab at the bottom is showing the error message.

Answer (score 2):

You can try one of the following:

- Set default project SDK to Python in **Project Structure | Project | Project SDK**
- Create your Python module as a [facet](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/facet-page.html) for the Java module, instead of a separate module.

I have created a usability issue for this https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-50547

Comment: The first one fixes the issue, but of course sets the workspace to default to python :). Thanks for opening the bug.